# Apache died; Suspect is ulimit but cannot reproduce

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, rhel6, ulimit

Apache died last night. Error log shows this

`[alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48`

Browsing around the Internet, everyone seems to say this is is an issue with ulimit in Linux. If I understand correctly, ulimit has a default to limit the number of concurrent processes to any non-root user to 1024. If that max number for a user (apache in this case) is reached, it can't create more processes. Thus explaining why it can't setuid to the apache user when it tried to spawn a new child.

Last night, we had a user of our web app make 1100+ GET requests to the same page in the space of about 1 minute and that's when the server died.

My Apache config file has this:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      2000
MaxClients       2000
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveTimeout 5
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

If my MaxClients is 2000 and the MaxSpareServers is 20, then that means in order for Apache to have hit the ulimit for processes, it would have had to have 1000+ *busy* processes, which I simply don't see that happening considering these GET requests were tiny and could easily handle 20-30 requests a second. On top of that, MaxRequestsPerChild is set to 4000, so it shouldn't be spawning so many new children, right? So was ulimit *really* the culprit here on why it couldn't setuid?

I've used Apache's `ab` tool to try and reproduce this on a much less powerful local build and I can't. Even the less powerful hardware can handle thousands of connections in one minute with *ok* performance. It goes slugish if I try to access the server via the web at the same time, but Apache doesn't go belly up.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a better way I configure the prefork module? We just migrated from an older server to this newer server. The older had the ServerLimit and MaxClients set to 512. I figured might as well set it 2000 to avoid having to change it again in the foreseeable future.
2. I've tried adjusting ulimit nproc to a LOW number to try and reproduce the error. In limits.conf I've set `*   hard  nproc    15`, but Apache would still spawn about 30 children when I would run `ab`. Am I missing something?
3. Despite number 2, is the solution here to raise the nproc setting to something higher like 10000?
4. I would also like to implement something that will prevent users from making so many attempts. In the past I've used `iptables` to block out users who made more than 5 SSH requests in a minute. I thought about doing something similar for http requests, but I wanted to know if there are better solutions out there. I've heard of fail2ban and mod_security and the such, but I'm not sure what they do. Would they benefit me in this case? Any other suggestions?

Server Info: RHEL 6.3, Apache 2.2.15

Comment: If you run ulimit as apache, what is the output?  What is listed in /etc/security/limits.conf (or wherever you have limits.conf or in limits.d...)?

Comment: limits.conf is the default, I haven't added anything. Soft limit for nproc is 1024 and hard limit is 15871. Thanks for the tip, I never thought about actually logging in as apache to check it. Doing so, I have verified that wen I do set limits in limits.conf, they are getting set. If I set my soft limit to 15, Apache will still spawn 32 processes, yet they're all marked with <Defunct>. At any rate, I haven't been able to reproduce the error. On my production I actually got a `[alert] Child 1283 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!`. I can't reproduce it or the setuid error

Comment: Though after I set really low levels in limits.conf, I would get the setuid error when trying to su into it manually, but I'm still not getting it from Apache when I start pounding the server with `ab`